# Ember.js IE TextField displaying "null" for null values

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm experiencing a strange bug in IE (9 and below, haven't tested 10), where null values in a controller will be displayed as a null string in textfields.

I've been able to isolate the problem in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AyKarsi/3bGN4/50/

The issue only  occurs if I fill the controller content with an ajax call, hence the

```
Ember.run.next(this, ..
```

to simulate the ajax call.

Chrome & Firefox work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It actually prints a string of null in IE if you replace an existing text field bound value with null, check updated fiddle to look at in IE:

http://jsfiddle.net/T4jxW/

I dont know if this is deliberate or a bug, but I've gotten around this issue by:

```
this.set('property', '');
```

instead of
    this.set('property', null);

I'll report it if I cant find some reason this is happening in IE(all versions), it also looks like sometimes in non IE browsers setting to null doesnt change the bound value at all, havent seen that consistantly though
if you've already reported let me know